# Proper way to queue system notifications?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, message-queue

I wrote the following jQuery plugin that is basically just a simple notification system used to display messages to the user.  This works great if you have 1 message to display at a time.  However, if you have multiple messages to display to the user they obviously display right on top of one another.

My question is, given this code, how would you recommend that I implement a message queuing system? I'd like to only show 1 message at a time, so when the close button is clicked or the fadeOut has completed, the next message would fire off and start the process.

My initial thought was to check if a message was already being displayed and maybe push this current message onto an array then pop it off when the first message is being remove, but I cannot seem to figure that out.

[JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ColdToast/zXVbr/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to display notifications in the order you receive them.  Use an array as a queue (`push(x)` to add a notifications to the end of the list, `shift()` to grab the next message received from the front of the queue).

Add a handle to detect when the message is closed or read, and then `shift()` the notifications queue to grab the next message to display, which will remove it from the queue.

Comment: I tried something similar to this approach but couldnt get the appropriate time to push it onto the array stack.  When would you do that? Immediately?

Comment: Any time you or the user has a notification, it can go into the queue.  You only display what is next after closing the notification.  Don't worry about what else is in there.